SQLAlchemy/DB allows for multiple records in association table for a two particular records-to-be-mapped, any way to ensure there will be only one?
Let's say it's just 3 tables:
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import AssociationProxy

import json

class Base(db.DeclarativeBase):
    #this will make the base class abstract, so it won't be mapped to a table.
    __abstract__ = True
    pass

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "usersTbl"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True) # primary keys are required by SQLAlchemy

    mileage = db.relationship('MileagePerChallenge', back_populates='user', lazy=True)
    challenges = association_proxy('mileage', 'challenge')

class Challenge(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "challengesTbl"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    mileage = db.relationship('MileagePerChallenge', back_populates='challenge', lazy=True)
    users = association_proxy('mileage', 'user')

class MileagePerChallenge(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "mileagePerchallengesTbl"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    userId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('usersTbl.id'), index=True)
    challengeId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('challengesTbl.id'), index=True)

    user = db.relationship('User', back_populates='mileage', lazy=True)
    challenge = db.relationship('Challenge', back_populates='mileage', lazy=True)

"MileagePerChallenge" is used as an association object. Each time when I run something like this:
chal_obj.users.append(user)

...for the same "chal_obj" and "user" objects, it creates a new record in the table representing the association object in DB. Which isn't something I expected, I thought the API (or DB) will be able to "figure out" it's a mapping entry and for each combination of userId X challengeId there will be only one entry in there.
What am I missing here? Is it how it's supposed to work, or perhaps I need to add some flag that will ensure only one association entry per each combination of IDs will be created?

What db are you using?

It's MySQL 8.0.36

Probably protect the table integrity with sqlalchemy.schema.UniqueConstraint, ie.
class MileagePerChallenge(db.Model):
    #...
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("userId", "challengeId"),)

Then depending on the db you can:

use an "upsert" to insert these links
consistently lock the challenge table row, read the link to see if it exists and then write it and release the lock if it doesn't
or catch the exception generated by the unique constraint being broken

